# Switch between %python variables and %sql variables in Databricks

Tags: python, sql, variables, databricks

I'm trying to switch between **%python** variables and **%sql** variables in Databricks SQL notebook.

Let's imagine this situation -

```
%python 
url_var = 'https://www.example.org/localdata_2020_01_01.csv'
```

```
%sql 
SET url_sql_var = $(url_var)
-- This doesn't work as expected
```

But this doesn't work because I'm not sure how to switch between Python & SQL variables in Databricks SQL notebooks.

Kindly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access python variable in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794549/how-can-i-access-python-variable-in-spark-sql)

Answer (score -1):

this is not possible . this is the way Databricks notebook has been configured . You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383182/how-do-i-export-variables-in-databricks-to-use-in-other-cells-using-sh/69384740#69384740)

Comment: it's possible, see linked answer

Comment: thanks for your details . I agree on your answer if same variable is being used across multiple cells (%python,%sql). But , consider this scenario . %python cell generating variable , if we want to use it in %sql cell is not possible . thats what my answer .