# How do I export variables in Databricks to use in other cells using sh?

Tags: bash, databricks

I have the following code in a databricks notebook:

```
%sh
export current_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo $current_date
> 2021-09-29
```

That works fine and for the current cell I can access and use the variable `$current_date`, however, if I try to call this variable in another cell I get empty as a result:

```
%sh
echo $current_date
>
```

This notebook might take more than one day to run, thus I want to define the current date when it starts running and use this value afterwards as a variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can work as workaround.

```
import os
my_var = "hello"
os.environ['MY_VAR'] = my_var
```

and then you can access MY_VAR variable something like this :

```
%sh
echo $MY_VAR
```

Answer (score 0):

This is way Databricks has been configured. When you invoke a language magic command in cell , the command is dispatched to the REPL in the execution context for the notebook.Variables defined in that cell  are not available in the REPL of another language/ another cell.
REPLs can share state only through external resources such as files in DBFS or objects in object storage. In your case , You are trying to use magic command in both cells . This is expected behavioral . Hope this helps you to understand.
Ref : https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#mix-languages